# Classic ASP AspXml createobject fails after windows updates (20212R2 - IIS8)

Tags: iis-8, createobject

Today our HTTP server had been updated with KB5001382, KB5001393 and KB5001403.
It's a windows server 2012R2 with IIS8 installed

But after those updates I started getting an error on one of my classic asp pages.

```
set xml0 = Server.CreateObject("AspXml.AspXml")
set xml = xml0.HttpGet(XML_File)
xml.FirstChild2() (error on this line)
```

Error message:
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'
Object required: 'xml'

I tested the XML_file and it loads fine local and on te server (browser).
My hosting provider says its something about case sensitivity but I can't imagine what they mean...

Comment: If the error is on the line where you try to access the Xml document, I'd say this isn't a problem of `CreateObject` and rather points to the `HttpGet` not retrieving the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer. 
I have the same problem with the msxml6.dll (msxml6.dll error '80070005' - Access is denied.). I found in an other question that it could be related to the IUSR account (no access to where the xml file resides).
No idea what that means though.

Comment: It means that the User Account your website runs on has no access to the file location - or in case of trying to access it via HttpGet, the User cannot access the network.

Comment: super! I'll get cracking. I hope this solves the problem or helps me in the right direction.
Regardless of the outcome thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure IIS and permissions to registry/files/folders related to the DLL involved.

1. Searched the registry for the Object name. In this case "AspXml.AspXml"
2. For all registry entries, you should take ownership of the parent registry folders, so please give read access to IIS user account.
3. Make sure the files/folders had read/execute permission for the IIS user account(s).
4. Registered the DLL at the command line for good measure.
5. Rebooted because restarting IIS didn't seem to do it.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for answering!
I tried your answer but without succes. I have placed the xml files local (same http domain) and everything works like a charm. So only reading remote xml files are blocked...